# Psalm 145:10 pronominal suffix surprise on verb 'to bless'

Tags: hebrew, psalms

The final verb in Psalm 146:10 (יבﬧכוכה - "And Thy Godly ones shall bless Thee") doesn't make sense to me. I would have expected a 'ך' (final 'כ') instead of 'כה.' Does its coming at the end of the verse have anything to do with this form of suffix?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's that **כה** (your in masculine singular) and **ך** mean the same thing, as we see in the *History of Hebrew Language* here https://www.adath-shalom.ca/history_of_hebrew3.htm

Indeed, כה is rarely used.

I would like to add some phrases to prove this (in **Psalms 139:5**):

> אָח֣וֹר וָקֶ֣דֶם צַרְתָּ֑נִי וַתָּ֖שֶׁת עָלַ֣י **כַּפֶּֽכָה**׃

which means:

> You hedge me before and behind; You lay Your hand upon me.

Above **כַּפֶּֽכָה** (your hand) is formed by **כַּף** (palm of hand) and the suffix **כָה** (your).

Another example is (**Proverbs 24:10**):

> הִ֭תְרַפִּיתָ בְּי֥וֹם צָרָ֗ה צַ֣ר **כֹּחֶֽכָה**׃

**כֹּחֶֽכָה** which is the junction of **כֹּחַ** (power, strengh) and the suffix **כָה** (your).

Comment: Thank you João. I'll look into verses!

Comment: If it did help, it's good to upvote ed huff in all answers.

Comment: @edhuff This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant Ps 145:10 and a certain numbers of the Psalms are different. In any event, the terminal Caph-Hey indicates the optative mood. The verse could be translated as follows:

> All the creatures you made will acknowledge you

> May your pious Bless [through] you

An example of the last verse is that when someone asks "How are you" they respond "Blessed be God".

I suggest in Joao's answer that the optative would nicely fit here. Here are the two verses with the optative mood indicated by the terminal hey in the translation

**Ps 139:5**

> You have fashioned me both in the past and in the future. Oh, I wish your hand to always support me

(Note: The linking word of "hand" in v5 and v10)

**Prv 24:10**

> You have become lazy/lax? [Then] I wish you to be in straights on a day of straights.

(Note the pun: "be in straights" "day of straights")

Personally, I have always advocated a careful nuanced reading of verses with translations that capture mood. It is quite dry to simply make every sentence indicative.

Comment: Thanks Russell. I'll do more digging into the optative by checking in with Gesenius. Also, should 'straight' be 'strait' as in dire straits (my fav band from long ago!)?